# Center view between other two views in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I try to center one textview between two others in relative layout. One text view is aligned to parent top, one to parrent bottom and third one (@id/info) is placed inbetween. I have following view hierarchy of list item used in ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_default"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_large"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_large"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_default" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_imageonly" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_default"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/best_prices_item_text_default"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priceQty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_default"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/best_prices_item_price"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gorceryName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/priceQty"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/best_prices_item_grocery_name"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xsmall"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/priceQty"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_default"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/best_prices_item_text_default"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In Eclipse view designer effect is as I would expect - textview is properly centered:

[image]

But when I run app on device/emulator centered textview is missing. Has anybody bumped on this issue and can help?

Comment: Change your Relative layout height from **wrap_content** to **match_parent**.

Comment: I have tried them both, result is the same

Comment: Hi, is your question already solved? i just tried your layout on emulator and nexus4 and it works fine...   Try to change values of `android:textColor="@color/best_prices_item_text_default" and android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"`

Comment: It almost works when I added rule `centerVertical`, it looks like middle textview is almost centered (I think that it is a bit above real center), but original layout that I posted is not working (missing middle textview), despite that in eclipse visual view designer it looks fine.

Answer (score 6):

try to use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`, `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` or `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`. Hope that helps.. Sometimes its better to use couple of LinearLayouts with different orientations, inside other LinearLayouts

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llFullContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="top"
        android:id="@+id/tvTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="middle"
        android:id="@+id/tvMiddle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tvBottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTop"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/tvBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing: android:gravity="center"